# Is an alphabet necessarily a regular language over it?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-expressions

[The definition of regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) says they are closed under union, concatenation, and Kleene star. Single symbols also form regular expressions/languages.

Since union is between two languages, does that mean that when the alphabet is infinitely countable, the language which is exactly the alphabet is not a regular language?

Thanks.

Comment: Most definitions of regular languages are made for finite alphabets, and the definitions break down in a number of ways when you try to make the alphabet infinite. (+1) in the hopes people more knowledgeable than me find this, but I don't know of any canonical way to solve this problem. My answer would have to be "regular languages over countable alphabets aren't well defined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discover this question after answering your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729046/why-can-regular-expressions-be-defined-without-mentioning-closure-under-intersec), but to avoid repetition, I will refer to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3729717) for definitions.

If $A$ is an infinite alphabet, then the set $A$ is not a *rational subset* of $A^*$. However, it is a *recognizable subset* of $A^*$. Indeed, let $F = \{1, a, 0\}$ be the finite monoid defined by $aa = a0 = 0a = 0$ and let $f: A^* \to F$ be the monoid morphism defined by $f(c) = a$ for each $c \in A$. Then $f(A) = \{a\}$ and $f^{-1}(a) = A$, since$f(1) = 1$ and $f(u) = 0$ if the length of $u$ is $\geqslant 2$.

This is a good illustration of the difference between rational and recognizable subsets.